# WP_Query Multiple Category Parameters not working

Tags: php, wordpress, search, parameters

**Situation:**
I cannot successfully a category parameter within WP_Query that searches within two categories mixing both OR and AND relationships.

**Explanation:**
I've got a search/filter that sorts by region, month, and year and it works great! When using the `category_name` parameter, it will successfully search for a region.

```
<?php // These grab data from the URL which are submitted by the form
$p_topi = $_GET['topic'];
$p_reg = $_GET['region'];
$p_mon = $_GET['mon'];
$p_year = (int) $_GET['yr'];
?>

<?php 
    $archive_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'thought_leadership',
        'category_name' => $p_reg, // Pay attention to this
        'year' => $p_year,
        'monthnum'=> $p_mon,
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
    );
    $archive_query = new WP_Query($archive_args);
    if ($archive_query->have_posts()) : while ($archive_query->have_posts()) : $archive_query->the_post(); ?>
```

I was asked to add sorting by topic. I tested it by replacing the  variable used with `category_name` and that worked well.

```
$archive_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'thought_leadership',
        'category_name'  => $p_topi, // Changed the variable to topic
        'year' => $p_year,
        'monthnum'=> $p_mon,
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
    );
```

I then tried combining the two variables and it sort of worked. Specifically, it worked as an OR operator, filtering by region or topic. It will not filter by both.

```
$archive_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'thought_leadership',
        'category_name'  => "$p_topi, $p_reg", // Combined the variables
        'year' => $p_year,
        'monthnum'=> $p_mon,
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
    );
```

I then tried using the `+` symbol to make the parameter accept both variables at the same time. It worked, but now it won't work as an OR operator. In other words, I have to select a topic and region, or the search won't find any results.

```
$archive_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'thought_leadership',
        'category_name'  => "$p_topi+$p_reg", // + makes it an AND operator
        'year' => $p_year,
        'monthnum'=> $p_mon,
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
    );
```

I researched WP_Query and found this excellent reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

I tried `category__and` but it returns with no posts matching that criteria.

```
$archive_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'thought_leadership',
        'category__and'  => array( 12, 5 ), // 12 = ID for topic, 5 = ID for region
        'year' => $p_year,
        'monthnum'=> $p_mon,
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
    );
```

I also tested `category__in` but found that it will not display children of a category. That's a problem because both topic and region have children. Like `category__and` it returns with no posts matching that criteria.

```
$archive_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'thought_leadership',
        'category__in'  => array( 12, 5 ),
        'year' => $p_year,
        'monthnum'=> $p_mon,
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
    );
```

As suggested by @Muhammad tayyab, I tried using `tax_query`. I got it work on an && basis.

```
$archive_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'thought_leadership',
        'year' => $p_year,
        'monthnum'=> $p_mon,
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category', // correct
                'field' => 'slug', // correct
                'terms' => $p_reg,
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category', // correct
                'field' => 'slug', // correct
                'terms' => $p_topi,
            )
        ,)
    );
```

But I couldn't successfully get the OR operator to work with nested arrays.

```
$archive_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'thought_leadership',
        'year' => $p_year,
        'monthnum'=> $p_mon,
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $p_reg,
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $p_reg,
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $p_topi,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

**Primary Question:**
Do you know of any way to create a search which will accept 0, 1 or 2 parameters? Said differently, I need to set it up so my users can search for region and/or topic or none at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is vague but this might help:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'tax_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => array( 'action', 'comedy' ),
      ),
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'actor',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
      ),
  ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can search by multiple taxonomies this way. You can use in `relation` to specify `and` or `not` relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I restated my question at the bottom and will check out the taxonomy parameter.

Comment: I just tried it and I could get the AND operator to work, but when using an OR operator and nesting, it didn't function. Any other help is super appreciated.